# How to set a property of UICollectionViewCell readonly eligantly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, readonly

I have a UITableViewCell `ProductsCell`, I registered it in a nib , and dequeue to use it.

I want to set a property of it readonly. How to do it better?

Here is the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MyProductsVC * targetMyProductsVC;

- (MyProductsVC *)targetMyProductsVC{

    if(!_targetMyProductsVC){
        UIResponder *target = self.nextResponder;
        do {
            target = target.nextResponder;
        } while (![target isKindOfClass: ZBMyProductsVC.self] && target != nil);
        _targetMyProductsVC = (ZBMyProductsVC *)target;

    }
    return _targetMyProductsVC;
}
```

I can't put the implementation. in `-init`,`-awakeFromNib` , because I use `UIResponder` to find the parent ViewController.

Because in above methods, the cell seems like have not been added on the super view.

If I do like this ,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MyProductsVC * targetMyProductsVC;
```

Xcode reports:

> Use of undeclared identifier '_targetMyProductsVC'

It is OK to set two property. one is inside like above , just set the other readonly property outside `getter` method (`return` the former property.)
It a little dirty ,

**any better way ?**

The code can work:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MyProductsVC * targetMyProductsVCReadOnly; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyProductsVC * targetMyProductsVC;


- (MyProductsVC *)targetMyProductsVC{

    if(!_targetMyProductsVC){
        UIResponder *target = self.nextResponder;
        do {
            target = target.nextResponder;
        } while (![target isKindOfClass: ZBMyProductsVC.self] && target != nil);
        _targetMyProductsVC = (ZBMyProductsVC *)target;

    }
    return _targetMyProductsVC; }


- (MyProductsVC *)targetMyProductsVCReadOnly{
    return self.targetMyProductsVC; }
```

Comment: Add r/w flag to your data source (or make another array with the same # of elements and populate that) and whenever it might change refresh the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are implementing your own property getter for a `readonly` property, which means there is only one accessor (i.e. there is no setter), the compiler will not automatically declare the backing variable. From [Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html):

> **Note**: The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a `readwrite` property, or a getter for a `readonly` property, the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.
>
> If you still need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be synthesized:
>
> ```
> @synthesize property = _property;
> ```

You insert the above before your getter implementation to resolve the *undeclared variable* error.

HTH

Comment: Or add `{ MyProductVC * _targetMyProductsVC }` behind `@implementation …`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - Apple's use of "need" in their last sentence is, as your comment illustrates, incorrectly emphatic. However there is some merit in Apple's approach in that it clearly ties the variable to the property, so it seemed appropriate to keep the answer simple by omitting the alternative. That said, I'll admit to using the alternative myself on occasions ;-)

Comment: I didn't want to criticizes your answer, just add a comment. This is, why I did not add an answer. However, synthesizing the way you explained has the advantage, that the type is automatically taken. On the other side explicit ivars have the advantage, that the type can differ – esp. it is possible to use a mutable subclass, what is useful for properties with a collection type.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - No criticism understood!